# Error when seeding mongoDB thru heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, mlab, mongoid4

Hello I have an app that I built on heroku and I can’t seem to get the mlab DB to work. It seems to connect but when I run heroku run rake db:setup I get an error and can’t see what it is.

I upgraded to a paid account but that hasn’t fixed the problem. Please help me figure this out. Here is my mongoid.yml file

```
# Tell Mongoid which environment this configuration is for. 
production:   
  sessions:
  default:
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>

development:   
  sessions:
  default:
  database: myapp_development
  hosts:
    - localhost:27017
  options:   options:

test:   
  sessions:
  default:
    database: myapp_test
    hosts:
      - localhost:27017
      options:
      read: primary
      max_retries: 1
      retry_interval: 0
```

My error is extremely long and I can’t seem to see the top lines but here is the top of what I can see.

`` /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.7/lib/moped/operation/read.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.7/lib/moped/node.rb:118:in `block in connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in with'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:63:in `handle_interrupt'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:63:in `block in with'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:60:in `handle_interrupt'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:60:in `with'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.7/lib/moped/node.rb:116:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.7/lib/moped/operation/read.rb:52:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.7/lib/moped/node.rb:608:in `[]'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.7/lib/moped/node.rb:608:in `block (3 levels) in flush’ ``

Thanks for any help.

BTW I am running mongoid 4.0.2 and rails 2.2.1

--UPDATE--

I ran 
`heroku run rake --trace db:setup`

I got this response...

`Running rake --trace db:setup on truenumbers-beta.... up, run.9099
** Invoke db:setup (first_time)
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:create
** Invoke db:mongoid:create_indexes (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Invoke db:mongoid:load_models (first_time)
** Execute db:mongoid:load_models
** Execute db:mongoid:create_indexes
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.573001 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} runtime: 15.4384ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.594073 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.158.94.215:11460 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} runtime: 10.7151ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.611470 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 COMMAND      database=heroku_q1xh85jr command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 1.3616ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.611875 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 INSERT       database=heroku_...db collection=system.indexes documents=[{:ns=>"heroku_...db.fs.files", :key=>{:filename=>1}, :name=>"filename_1"}] flags=[]
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.611965 #3] DEBUG -- :                              COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 10.7461ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.618998 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 2.2909ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.619499 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 INSERT       database=heroku_...db collection=system.indexes documents=[{:ns=>"heroku_...db.fs.files", :key=>{:aliases=>1}, :name=>"aliases_1"}] flags=[]
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.619588 #3] DEBUG -- :                              COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 6.9291ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.635347 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 1.2759ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.635548 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 INSERT       database=heroku_...db collection=system.indexes documents=[{:ns=>"heroku_...db.fs.files", :key=>{:uploadDate=>1}, :name=>"uploadDate_1"}] flags=[]
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.635637 #3] DEBUG -- :                              COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 15.4409ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.641401 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 1.2005ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.641598 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 INSERT       database=heroku_...db collection=system.indexes documents=[{:ns=>"heroku_...db.fs.files", :key=>{:md5=>1}, :name=>"md5_1"}] flags=[]
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.641683 #3] DEBUG -- :                              COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 5.4224ms
I, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.641804 #3]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Created indexes on Mongoid::GridFs::Fs::File:
I, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.641914 #3]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Index: {:filename=>1}, Options: {}
I, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.641988 #3]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Index: {:aliases=>1}, Options: {}
I, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.642066 #3]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Index: {:uploadDate=>1}, Options: {}
I, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.642166 #3]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Index: {:md5=>1}, Options: {}
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.648954 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 1.1073ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.649090 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 INSERT       database=heroku_...db collection=system.indexes documents=[{:unique=>true, :ns=>"heroku_...db.fs.chunks", :key=>{:files_id=>1, :n=>-1}, :name=>"files_id_1_n_-1"}] flags=[]
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.649137 #3] DEBUG -- :                              COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 5.3409ms
I, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.649182 #3]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Created indexes on Mongoid::GridFs::Fs::Chunk:
I, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.649234 #3]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Index: {:files_id=>1, :n=>-1}, Options: {:unique=>true}
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.656835 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 1.0796ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.656969 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 INSERT       database=heroku_...db collection=system.indexes documents=[{:background=>true, :ns=>"heroku_...db.tenants", :key=>{:invitation_token=>1}, :name=>"invitation_token_1"}] flags=[]
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.657016 #3] DEBUG -- :                              COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 7.2313ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.663727 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 1.1747ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.663903 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 INSERT       database=heroku_...db collection=system.indexes documents=[{:background=>true, :ns=>"heroku_...db.tenants", :key=>{:invitation_by_id=>1}, :name=>"invitation_by_id_1"}] flags=[]
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.663989 #3] DEBUG -- :                              COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 6.2813ms
I, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.664065 #3]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Created indexes on Tenant:
I, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.664166 #3]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Index: {:invitation_token=>1}, Options: {:background=>true}
I, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.664240 #3]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Index: {:invitation_by_id=>1}, Options: {:background=>true}
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.672419 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 1.3468ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.672824 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 INSERT       database=heroku_...db collection=system.indexes documents=[{:background=>true, :ns=>"heroku_...db.managers", :key=>{:invitation_token=>1}, :name=>"invitation_token_1"}] flags=[]
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.672911 #3] DEBUG -- :                              COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 7.8967ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.679652 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 1.7443ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.679844 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 INSERT       database=heroku_...db collection=system.indexes documents=[{:background=>true, :ns=>"heroku_...db.managers", :key=>{:invitation_by_id=>1}, :name=>"invitation_by_id_1"}] flags=[]
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.680187 #3] DEBUG -- :                              COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 6.4280ms
I, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.681679 #3]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Created indexes on Manager:
I, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.682260 #3]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Index: {:invitation_token=>1}, Options: {:background=>true}
I, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.682339 #3]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Index: {:invitation_by_id=>1}, Options: {:background=>true}
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.690098 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 2.1209ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.698085 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 INSERT       database=heroku_...db collection=system.indexes documents=[{:background=>true, :ns=>"heroku_...db.blog_posts", :key=>{:tags=>1}, :name=>"tags_1"}] flags=[]
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.698350 #3] DEBUG -- :                              COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 14.8885ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.714160 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 8.2012ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.715702 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 INSERT       database=heroku_...db collection=system.indexes documents=[{:background=>true, :ns=>"heroku_...db.blog_posts", :key=>{:keywords=>1}, :name=>"keywords_1"}] flags=[]
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.715800 #3] DEBUG -- :                              COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 16.5160ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.731378 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 6.8590ms
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.732511 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 INSERT       database=heroku_...db collection=system.indexes documents=[{:background=>true, :ns=>"heroku_...db.blog_posts", :key=>{:type=>1}, :name=>"type_1"}] flags=[]
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.732602 #3] DEBUG -- :                              COMMAND      database=heroku_...db command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 15.9511ms
I, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.732759 #3]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Created indexes on Blog::Post:
I, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.732872 #3]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Index: {:tags=>1}, Options: {:background=>true}
I, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.732999 #3]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Index: {:keywords=>1}, Options: {:background=>true}
I, [2016-03-29T19:51:17.733300 #3]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Index: {:type=>1}, Options: {:background=>true}
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Execute db:seed
D, [2016-03-29T19:51:23.970070 #3] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 10.164.48.254:11460 QUERY        database=heroku_...db collection=tenants selector={"email"=>"lizeth_larson@pollich.io"} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields={:_id=>1} runtime: 4.9172ms`

It seems to be creating the db but not able to seed it. However when I go and look at the db nothing is their which makes me think maybe it starts building the db and when the seed fails it destroys what it did.

Comment: Is this on `production` or which environment? `production` looks wrong. Take a look at [MongoDB won't connect to MongoHQ using Mongoid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801977/mongodb-wont-connect-to-mongohq-using-mongoid) which shows correct splitting of the URI.

Comment: Yes this is on production. The funny thing is that this app is a clone of one of my other apps where the production works fine. I just created a new do and have not gotten it to work. I will take a look at your link.

Comment: I see the answer about changing the yml but where do the variables go? such as (uri.path)? DO I put that in my heroku variables and what part of the uri should that be? Can you show how that variable would look in the heroku variables? –

Comment: Made the changes but I still cant setup the db. I am getting the same error. I dont believe the mongoid.yml is causing the error. the way it is above does pass a heroku deploy. It just isnt working to setup the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the DB I was using in development was an older version of MongoDB. I upgraded to MongoDB 5 and everything worked after a little revision.